# Unable to create domain in plesk

Tags: windows, server, plesk

I had a domain on my server in plesk for several years then recently deleted the folder and from IIS.  I now am trying to add it back using Plesk and am getting the following error:

Error: ProtDir_IIS::update() failed: Add Protected Directory failed: columns siteId, path are not unique at execute console command -add-protected-url(vconsoleapp::start line 100) at execute "C:\Program Files (x86)\Parallels\Plesk\admin\bin64\websrvmng.exe"

1. I deleted the vhosts\domain folder
2. I deleted the domain from IIS
3. I deleted the domain from Plesk

I just can't figure out what is keeping it locked and/or protected.  Any ideas much appreciated.

Comment: SO is a programming Q&A platform and this question is not about programming. Please delete this

Answer (score 0):

Access your server through Remote Desktop ( RDP ) and run the following command.

> “%plesk_cli%\repair.exe” –synchronize-protected-directories-storage

The server's directories will be synchronized with this command.  In IIS manager, remove unnecessary entries for this domain where you are receiving error messages after you run this command. If you have Mail enable post office enabled, you may also need to remove entries from the post office.

You should be able to add your domain now.

Comment: thanks for the feedback and I did see this same example on another post, however I cannot get the command to work for me, I keep getting:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Parallels\Plesk\bin>repair -synchronized-protected-direct
ories-storge
Unknown command: -synchronized-protected-directories-storge

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to get the command line tool to work.  I resolved my issue by updating to Plesk Onyx From Plesk 12, I realized I was on a pretty old outdated version.  Now I can add the web site(s) with no issues.